# Play streaming video from video tag to canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, video-streaming

i'm working on a website with video streaming, the video is actually in a video tag but i need to draw on it so i'm trying to send the streaming from the video tag to canvas with no luck, already read severeal similar questions over here with not luck either, any suggestion? this is the current way i'm testing with no luck:

```
var VIDEOELEMENT = document.getElementById("camchat"); //Video Tag
var canvas2 = document.getElementById('myCanvas'); //Canvas Tag
var ctx = canvas2.getContext('2d');

VIDEOELEMENT.addEventListener('play', () => {
        console.log("INITIATING VIDEO PLAY");
    function step() {
    ctx.drawImage(VIDEOELEMENT, 0, 0, canvas2.width, canvas2.height)
    requestAnimationFrame(step)
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(step);
})
```

Comment: What do you need to draw on top? Because you can actually place items over a video on HTML (for instance HTML5 video players put controls over the video). Maybe this could be a solution instead of a canvas?

Comment: @Tim face filter like snapchat, i'm using the jeelizFaceFilter JS library, but all the demos/examples are using the device camera, in this case i don't want to use the camera but the streaming in the video tag

Comment: There is no play event. Did you meant playing?